# Simple query on a large MySQL table takes very long time at first, much quicker later

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

We are struggling with a slow query that only happens the first time it is called. Afterwards the query is much faster. 
The first time the query is done, it takes anywhere from 15-20 seconds. Subsequent calls take < 1.5 seconds. However if not called again for a few hours, the query will take 15-20 seconds again.

The table is a table of daily readings for an entity called system(foreign key), with system id, date, sample reading, and an indication if the reading is done (past). The query asks for a range of 1 year of samples (365 days) for 200 selected systems.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT system_id, 
       sample_date, 
       reading 
FROM Dailyreadings  
 WHERE past = 1  
  AND reading IS NOT NULL 
  AND sample_date < '2014-02-25' AND sample_date >= DATE('2013-01-26')  
  AND system_id IN (list_of_ids)
```

list_of_ids represents a list of 200 system ids for which we want the readings.

We have an index on system_id, sample_date and an index on both. The result of the query usually gives back ~70,000 rows. And when using explain on the query, I can see the index is used, and the planning is to only go over ~70,000 rows.

The MySQL is on amazon RDS. The engine for all table is innodb.

The Dailyreadings table has about 60 million rows, so it is quite large. However I can't understand how a very simple range query, can take up to 20 seconds. This is done on a read only replica, so concurrent writes aren't an issue I would guess. This also happens on a staging copy of the DB which has very few read/write requests going on at the same time.

After reading many many questions about slow first time queries, I assume the problem is that the first time, the query needs to be read from the disk, and afterwards it is cached. However, I fail to see why such a simple query would take so much time reading from disk. I also tried many tweaks to the innodb parameters, and couldn't get this to improve. Even doubling the ram of the system didn't seem to help.

Any pointers as to what could be the problem? and how we can improve the time it takes for the first query? Any ideas how to pinpoint the exact problem?

- edit 
  It seems the problem might be in the  IN clause, which is slow since the list is big (200) items?. Is this a known issue? Is there a way to accelerate this?

Comment: The query runs fast after a run because mysql is caching it probably. To see how your query runs with caching disabled try: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE system_id ...`

Comment: Is you covering index on the sample_date and system_id, or the other way round? Is sample_date a date type field?

Comment: The sample_date is indeed a date field. The index is for system_id(1) and then sample_date(2), should I change the order? Think it will help?

Comment: I would try it the other way round, as at least then it is only having to check a range once. The other way round it would seem it needs to check the range for each system id.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Still trying to understand what exactly is the bottle neck here, and how a simple query with no joins is taking such a long time.

Comment: Finding odd cases like this is always difficult. 200 items in an IN clause is quite large and it might be worth a try rewriting this to use a table of those 200 ids with a JOIN to Dailyreadings. I doubt it would help directly but could be interesting to compare. Could be that the bottleneck is just the time taken to analyze the text and work out if it is valid SQL and what to do with it, with the resulting plan (if not the results) being cached.

Comment: I tried adding the new index and there was no difference I could see. However I tried to get rid of the IN clause as suggested, by just a test of joining with 200 systems from the system table. And indeed the query time drops significantly! It seems the in clause is the problem. Is this normal? It's very hard for me to get rid of the IN clause, since I need to do a lot of different processing (in the application code) before I decide which systems to pull. So basically my input is the list of systems. Is there anyways to do such a query, without the IN clause?

Comment: You could take your list of systems and put them into a temp table, then join that temp table in your query instead of using the IN. Can be worthwhile sometimes. IN seems to perform well for small numbers of items but seems to struggle as the number goes up. What kind of difference did it make to the execution time?

Comment: After carefully analyzing, it's only about 20% faster. So the query is still too slow. Can't figure out the reason. If only I could force this entire table to stay in cache the entire time...

Comment: Did the temp table have an index on the id field?

Answer (score 0):

The query runs fast after a run because mysql is caching it probably. To see how your query runs with caching disabled try: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE system_id ...`

Also, I found that comparing dates on tables with lots of data has a negative effect on performance. When possible, I saved the dates as ints using unix timestamps and compared the dates like that and it worked faster.

Comment: The SQL_NO_CACHE doesn't make a difference, I think there is the innodb caching mechanism itself and other things that go on. Even with the SQL_NO_CACHE flag, I didn't notice a significant change. The date field change sounds like it can help, although doesn't sql save the DATE type in an efficient way?